# Нету звука в наушниках , но есть на динамиках ноутбук Ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: linux, ubuntu, аудио

Недавно установил Ubuntu звук на динамиках ноутбука есть , а в наушниках нету.Pavucontrol показывает что звук с браузера идет но её нету.
lspci
[image: lspci]

Comment: В pavucontrol последняя вкладка "конфигурация". Там попробуйте сменить профиль, например с "Аналоговый стерео выход" на "Аналоговый стерео дуплекс" или наоборот.

Comment: В третьей вкладке "устройства вывода" появляются наушники в списке при подключении?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Профили менял безуспешно , в 3 вкладке появляются

Comment: Если появляются, то выберите их и попробуйте нажать на кнопку "set as fallback" вверху справа. Если всё работает, то при воспроизведении звука при выбранных наушниках должна полоска снизу отображать громкость.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf я нажал но ничего не воспроизводится но полоска шевелится

Comment: Это конечно маловероятно, но возможно у вас [заглушен звук](https://i.imgur.com/4P28j6m.png)?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Увы не заглушен:(

Comment: Ну да, она бы не шевелилась если бы звук был заглушен... Возможно, проблема в самих наушниках или разъёме.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Наушники проверял , рабочие

Comment: Jack sense либо не поддерживается, либо надо указать соответствующий quirk для драйвера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pactl load-module module-detect`Решил воспользоваться этой командой вроде все работает